# Can a python module be imported without installing

Tags: python-3.x, libraries, python-import, spyder

Is this possible that a module is imported without installing the same. If no then why is my spyder IDE is showing a warning on the line where it is written import nltk even when nltk is not installed

Comment: If I read your question correctly, it seems like you are asking why is spyder showing a warning statement at "import nltk" even when nltk is not installed.  Isn't that expected behavior?  Am I missing something?

Comment: What happens when you run `import nltk`?

Comment: I am sorry . I missed the important problem. It shows a warning that states 'nltk imported but unused'.

Comment: how does it say nltk imported way before installing it

Answer (score 1):

Spyder runs a static analysis on the code you have in the *Editor* to offer hints and errors about it.

Since the analysis is static, it means Spyder doesn't run your code to perform it. In your case it simply detects that you have a line like

```
import nltk
```

but that there's no other use or call to `nltk` (for example, with a code like `nltk.pos_tag(tokens)` or something like that).