# python import file path relative inside a import module / use module without installing

Tags: python

How do I import a module and use it as if I installed it without actually installing it? More specifically, when I do imports on an installed module, all the imports are relative to the module. However when I just import it, all the imports are relative to the module it is called from.

As a specific example, in the below I would like `run_import.py` to print `module` not `parent`. But because it imports `cfg` from the parent not the module, it prints the wrong one. I would like to be able to run `module1` on a standalone basis and have it isolated from any code that is calling it, much like you would in an installed package.

Directory structure is

```py
module1/
  __init__.py
  cfg.py
  tasks.py
  run_module.py
  utils.py
cfg.py  
run_import.py
utils.py
```

Code

```py
# cfg.py
level = 'parent'

# module1/cfg.py
level='module'

# module1/tasks.py

import cfg

def run_it():
    print(cfg.level)

# module1/run_module.py

import tasks

tasks.run_it() # prints 'module'

# module1/utils.py

def util_fun():
    print('util module')

# utils.py

def util_fun():
    print('util parent')

# run_import.py

import module1.tasks as tasks

tasks.run_it() # prints 'parent', would like it to print 'module'

import utils
utils.util_fun() # prints util parent, should not print util module
```

This give me what I was looking for but has the unintended consequence that everything gets imported relative to that module

```py
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "module1")

tasks.run_it() # prints 'parent'

import utils
utils.util_fun() # prints util module, not util parent
```

Here are a couple of answers I have looked it, they didn't seem to solve it.

[What's the purpose of the "__package__" attribute in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21233229/whats-the-purpose-of-the-package-attribute-in-python) this sounds like what is needed but not sure how that can be set

[Python3 importlib.util.spec_from_file_location with relative path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48841150/python3-importlib-util-spec-from-file-location-with-relative-path) look potentially promising but i'm not sure how to use it, particularly not sure what the file path should be

[How to use a packed python package without installing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48746494/how-to-use-a-packed-python-package-without-installing-it)

[Import a module from a relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/import-a-module-from-a-relative-path)

[Can a python module be imported without installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42770950/can-a-python-module-be-imported-without-installing)

[Import module using relative paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57150623/import-module-using-relative-paths)

Answer (score 0):

When you execute `run_import.py`, the imports are searching in the root folder (`module1/`).

So you can try changing `module1/tasks.py`

```
from module1 import cfg

def run_it():
    print(cfg.level)
```

Comment: Yes that would work but I would like to be able to run `module1` on a standalone basis and have it isolated from any code that is calling it, much like you would in an installed package.

Comment: Well it's a known problem in the python world, if you run a python file, it can not import modules above itself. A work-around is to keep all the main/executable files at the top-level of your project, and create subfolders for utils/test files. See here: https://www.patricksoftwareblog.com/structure-of-a-python-project/

Answer (score 0):

Try this, adding the module to the path works if you would only like to change `run_import.py`

```py
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "module1")

from module1 import tasks
tasks.run_it()
```

Comment: This works but has the unintended consequence that everything gets imported relative to that module now, see updated question